# Youtrack workflow via JS - Unable to compare estimation and spent time

Tags: youtrack

I just want to compare 2 periods (e.g. i want to compare between 3w4d23h58m and 20h in order to track time). All i got is

[image: 1]

I need to convert this PT2H to just 2 hours to count percentage between estimation and spent time.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/v1-PeriodProjectCustomField.html?q=getMinutes

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from a workflow that calculates remaining time by subtracting spent time from estimation:

```
action: (ctx) => {
    const issue = ctx.issue;
    var periodestimate = issue.Estimation;
    var minutesestimate = !periodestimate ? 0 : (periodestimate.getMinutes() + 60 * (periodestimate.getHours() + 8 * (periodestimate.getDays() + 5 * periodestimate.getWeeks())));
    var periodspent = ctx.issue.fields.SpentTime;
    var minutesspent = !periodspent ? 0 : (periodspent.getMinutes() + 60 * (periodspent.getHours() + 8 * (periodspent.getDays() + 5 * periodspent.getWeeks())));
    var remain = minutesestimate - minutesspent;
    ctx.issue.fields.Remaining = dateTime.toPeriod(remain + 'm');
  },
```

I suppose that you can use it as an example to calculate the needed percentage.

Comment: Hi Alisa! Tnx for your reply. This code works fine  in case of "var remain = minutesestimate - minutesspent;" when minutesestimate is bigger than minutesspent

but its possible that minutesspent > minutesestimate  so I see error "Value -60m cannot be parsed"

Comment: Hello Konstantyn! You can add something like this to handle such scenario:

    var remain = minutesestimate - minutesspent;
    if (remain >= 0) {
 ctx.issue.fields.Remaining = dateTime.toPeriod(remain + 'm');
 }
 else if (remain < 0) {
 ctx.issue.fields.Remaining = null;
 }

Of course, you can replace `ctx.issue.fields.Remaining = null;` with any other value.